# Multdimensional array list

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion

can someone help me create a recursive function to print out this array in a list ul>li>ul.children etc. Thanks! :)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 139
            [title] => Young People
            [pid] => 0
            [live] => 1
            [displayOrder] => 255
            [custom1] => 
            [custom2] => 
            [custom3] => 
            [live_id] => 
            [lastUpdated] => 1411839635
            [owner_id] => 1
            [availableFrom] => 1411772400
            [availableUntil] => 
            [type] => catTypeOne
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 143
                            [title] => Leadership & Development
                            [pid] => 139
                            [live] => 0
                            [displayOrder] => 255
                            [custom1] => 
                            [custom2] => 
                            [custom3] => 
                            [live_id] => 
                            [lastUpdated] => 1411839613
                            [owner_id] => 
                            [availableFrom] => 1411839613
                            [availableUntil] => 
                            [type] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 144
                            [title] => Cat 1
                            [pid] => 139
                            [live] => 0
                            [displayOrder] => 255
                            [custom1] => 
                            [custom2] => 
                            [custom3] => 
                            [live_id] => 
                            [lastUpdated] => 1411840264
                            [owner_id] => 
                            [availableFrom] => 1411840264
                            [availableUntil] => 
                            [type] => 
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 145
                                            [title] => Cat 2
                                            [pid] => 144
                                            [live] => 0
                                            [displayOrder] => 255
                                            [custom1] => 
                                            [custom2] => 
                                            [custom3] => 
                                            [live_id] => 
                                            [lastUpdated] => 1411840268
                                            [owner_id] => 
                                            [availableFrom] => 1411840268
                                            [availableUntil] => 
                                            [type] => 
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 146
                                                            [title] => Cat 3
                                                            [pid] => 145
                                                            [live] => 0
                                                            [displayOrder] => 255
                                                            [custom1] => 
                                                            [custom2] => 
                                                            [custom3] => 
                                                            [live_id] => 
                                                            [lastUpdated] => 1411840274
                                                            [owner_id] => 
                                                            [availableFrom] => 1411840274
                                                            [availableUntil] => 
                                                            [type] => 
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 147
                                                            [title] => Cat 4
                                                            [pid] => 145
                                                            [live] => 0
                                                            [displayOrder] => 255
                                                            [custom1] => 
                                                            [custom2] => 
                                                            [custom3] => 
                                                            [live_id] => 
                                                            [lastUpdated] => 1411840281
                                                            [owner_id] => 
                                                            [availableFrom] => 1411840281
                                                            [availableUntil] => 
                                                            [type] => 
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 148
                                                            [title] => Cat 5
                                                            [pid] => 145
                                                            [live] => 0
                                                            [displayOrder] => 255
                                                            [custom1] => 
                                                            [custom2] => 
                                                            [custom3] => 
                                                            [live_id] => 
                                                            [lastUpdated] => 1411840288
                                                            [owner_id] => 
                                                            [availableFrom] => 1411840288
                                                            [availableUntil] => 
                                                            [type] => 
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 141
            [title] => Careers Guidance
            [pid] => 0
            [live] => 0
            [displayOrder] => 255
            [custom1] => 
            [custom2] => 
            [custom3] => 
            [live_id] => 
            [lastUpdated] => 1411839580
            [owner_id] => 
            [availableFrom] => 1411839580
            [availableUntil] => 
            [type] => catTypeOne
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Print the array in a list format? What exactly do you want outputted (i.e. provide sample / desired output)? What does your current code look like that attempts to create this display (i.e. what have you tried)?

Answer (score 0):

This will nest `<ul>`s arbitrarily deep. each `<ul>` will have a class of `level#`, where `#` is an integer starting with 0 at the top level.

```
function make_list($array, $level = 0)
{
  $ret = "<ul class=\"level$level\">";
  foreach($array as $sub)
  {
    if(is_array($sub))
    {
      $sub = make_list($sub, $level + 1);
    }
    $ret .= "\n<li>$sub</li>";
  }
  $ret .= "\n</ul>";
  return $ret;
}
```

assuming your original array is called `$my_array`, you can call it like this:

```
echo make_list($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function that displays one level. Each time you encounter a subarray call the function recursively on that subarray. Before and after each call to the function write the ul tags.